# Shell Script does not capture values inside ENDSSH

Tags: shell, bash

I am very new to writing Shell scripts and am trying to write a simple script to run Vagrant up then SSH into the box and run some commands. The `echo Hi there` will run but the `read -p` will never show. Am I doing this wrong or is there a work around of some sort?

```
vagrant ssh default << 'ENDSSH'
read -p "Enter your first name:" FIRST_NAME
echo Hi there
ENDSSH
```

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355639/shell-script-does-not-capture-values-inside-endssh "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Answer (score 0):

Inside if a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) you can substitute variables, but it won't run any commands unless you put them in command substitution (`$()`).  Put your `read` before the `vagrant` and use the resulting variable in your heredoc.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Would you happen to know another work around though? This is a basic example, but I want to call another script within the `ENDSSH` which has `read` in it but won't run inside there (the method you recommended just won't be applicable to my scenario). Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for not noticing this comment earlier.  Command substitution should let you do what you're looking for. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html